# Appending Pandas DataFrame in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, append

Let's say I have a `df` such as this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'A_z': [2,3,4,5,6], 'B': [3,4,5,6,7], 'B_z': [4,5,6,7,8], 
                  'C': [5,6,7,8,9], 'C_z': [6,7,8,9,10]})
```

Which looks like this:

```
   A  A_z  B  B_z  C  C_z
0  1    2  3    4  5    6
1  2    3  4    5  6    7
2  3    4  5    6  7    8
3  4    5  6    7  8    9
4  5    6  7    8  9   10
```

What I'm looking to do is create a new `df` and for each letter (A,B,C) append this new `df` vertically with the data from the two columns per letter so that it looks like this:

```
    Letter  Letter_z
0        1         2
1        2         3
2        3         4
3        4         5
4        5         6
5        3         4
6        4         5
7        5         6
8        6         7
9        7         8
10       5         6
11       6         7
12       7         8
13       8         9
14       9        10
```

As far as I'm concerned something like this should work fine:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col[-1] != 'z':
        new_df = new_df.append(df[[col, col + '_z']])
```

However this results in the following mess:

```
     A  A_z    B  B_z    C   C_z
0  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
1  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
2  3.0  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
3  4.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
4  5.0  6.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
0  NaN  NaN  3.0  4.0  NaN   NaN
1  NaN  NaN  4.0  5.0  NaN   NaN
2  NaN  NaN  5.0  6.0  NaN   NaN
3  NaN  NaN  6.0  7.0  NaN   NaN
4  NaN  NaN  7.0  8.0  NaN   NaN
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0   6.0
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  6.0   7.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  7.0   8.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  8.0   9.0
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  9.0  10.0
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be really appreciated, cheers.

EDIT:

After the kind help from jezrael the renaming of the columns in his answer got me thinking about a possible way to do it using my original train of thought.

I can now also achieve the new `df` I want using the following:

```
for col in df:
    if col[-1] != 'z':
        d = df[[col, col + '_z']]
        d.columns = ['Letter', 'Letter_z']
        new_df = new_df.append(d)
```

The different columns names were clearly what was causing the problem which is something I wasn't aware of at the time. Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: Explicit loops should be a last resort in Pandas. Can’t you just append the columns “manually”? You could also concat all even-numbered columns, then all the odd-numbered columns, and combine the two. I am curious to know what the use case for this is.

Comment: Hi mate, unfortunately I can't my real df is quite big. Also I just tried manually appending, doing `new_df = new_df.append(df[['A', 'A_z']])` etc etc and it results in the same problem.

Comment: Re: your edit, I really wouldn't recommend that style/design when working with Pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One ide is use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for `MultiIndex`, then use `rename` for avoid `NaN`s and finally new columns names, reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), sort for correct order by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last remove `MultiIndex`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x:'Letter_z' if x == 'z' else 'Letter', level=1)
df = df.stack(0).sort_index(level=[1,0]).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    Letter  Letter_z
0        1         2
1        2         3
2        3         4
3        4         5
4        5         6
5        3         4
6        4         5
7        5         6
8        6         7
9        7         8
10       5         6
11       6         7
12       7         8
13       8         9
14       9        10
```

Or if possible simplify problem with reshape all non `z` values to one column and all `z` values to another use `numpy.ravel`:

```
m = df.columns.str.endswith('_z')

a = df.loc[:, ~m].to_numpy().T.ravel()
b = df.loc[:, m].to_numpy().T.ravel()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Letter': a,'Letter_z': b})
print (df)
    Letter  Letter_z
0        1         2
1        2         3
2        3         4
3        4         5
4        5         6
5        3         4
6        4         5
7        5         6
8        6         7
9        7         8
10       5         6
11       6         7
12       7         8
13       8         9
14       9        10
```

Comment: Hi mate thanks for both those answers, I've ended up using the bottom answer. Cheers!

Comment: Don't use `.values`. If you need a NumPy array, there's always `to_numpy()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) and a list comprehension:

```
cols = df.columns[~df.columns.str.endswith('_z')]
func = lambda x: 'letter_z' if x.endswith('_z') else 'letter'
pd.concat([df.filter(like=i).rename(func, axis=1) for i in  cols])
```

or

```
cols = df.columns[~df.columns.str.endswith('_z')]
pd.concat([df.filter(like=i).set_axis(['letter', 'letter_z'], axis=1, inplace=False) for i in  cols])
```